# category name for grouping: videos, podcast, blog

Tags: menu, web

I need to find a category name for a top menu on a website
for grouping: 
videos, podcast episodes, blog.

I'm thinking "content"

Is there a better category to group all of those options? Content doesn't say much I'm guessing...

Comment: Might not be a good fit but sharing the screenshot or creating a mockup with the exact top menu, would make more sense and appealing advise/solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Resources or Free Resources,
- Help ( generally all materials videos, how to's, tips will be placed),
- Tutorials (if its education - then submenu as videos, podcasts etc),
- Collections ( i think wont work, it will be good for fashion related websites)